# SQL Server Database with heavily used table

Tags: sql-server, performance, optimization, database-administration

I'm working on an application with a table which the rest of the schema is designed around (it's essentially a person table).

However there are intermittent performance issues whilst accessing the table through various places in the code especially when the application is under heavy use.

Is there any mechanism to reduce the load on a table like this to prevent locks etc. Overall the SQL in the database is not badly written and is pretty simple and performant.

Comment: Have you got indexes on columns that are normally queried?

Comment: Horizontal partitioning or caching

Comment: Do you use snapshot isolation mode? Try it.

Comment: As stated your question boils down to "how do I optimize", which is hard to impossible to answer well -- unless you're writing a book on it.

Comment: I've heard of snapshot mode when doing the SQL Server exam, but I didn't realise there is an option to set it globally. The cost of updating each individual query would be preventative, and data consistency isn't a massive priority in this context. e.g. we're not taking payments or anything.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how frequently this is updated and how important atomic transactions are, one option is to do "dirty" reads using the nolock hint:

```
select ... from MY_TABLE with (nolock)
```

This prevents selects from locking the table and blocking other transactions. This can also be done globally through some settings although doing it on a per-query level gives you the option to still have selects that lock.

Try to make the table's primary key clustered if possible, this can also help performance and avoids a "hop" when reading from it.

Comment: Whether `NOLOCK` is appropriate also depends on how attached you are to getting consistent results. Although `NOLOCK` will do as it promises (take no locks), liberal and thoughtless use of `NOLOCK` ("it's faster!") is a source of potential problems (when querying totals, for example). If you consider a solution using `NOLOCK` (`READ UNCOMMITTED`) it is at least worthwhile to look at snapshot isolation as well, as it also eliminates locking but without the consistency issues -- well, without *those* consistency issues, you do need to take care of update conflicts.

Comment: I like the idea of setting dirty reads globally. It would be too big a task to change all queries in the system individually to prevent locking. Obviously there is a risk of users receiving inconsistent results with dirty reads, but this seams less of a problem than functions failing due to locking.